# How to implement a method for multiple strategies having completely different logic?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I find it hard to give this question a concret title, as I'm not really aware of how to name my type of problem. Any suggestions welcome.

I have a service to run logic that literally performs the same action (eg save a thumbnail), but contains completely different logic for different providers:

```
@Service
public class ThumbnailService {
    public void saveForProvider1(Prov1 url) {

    }

    public void saveForProvider2(Prov2 url) {
        //completely different logic than Provider1; also a different parameter Object "Prov2"
    }
}
```

**Problem 1**: for any new `provider` I have to create an additional method in that `ThumbnailService`.

Now at a specific point, I want to run those methods async:

```
//basically just an async wrapper service
@Service
@Async
public class ThumbnailServiceAsync {
    @Autowired
    private ThumbnailService delegator;

    public class asyncSaveForProvider1(Prov1 url) { 
        delegator.saveForProvider1(url);
    }

    public class asyncSaveForProvider2(Prov2 url) { 
        delegator.saveForProvider2(url);
    }
}
```

Switching by an`Integer` variable where I know which number stands for which provider:

```
int provider;
switch (provider) {
    case 1: thumbServiceAsync.asyncSaveForProvider1(url); break;
    case 2: thumbServiceAsync.asyncSaveForProvider2(url); break;
    default: throw NotSupportedException();
}
```

**Problem 2**: as you see I'm writing lots of code just for the sake of delegation to the specific provider routine. And I also have to touch at least those 3 classes mentioned when introduction any additional provider.

Question: how could I optimize this process? Especially regarding that by time more providers may be implemented. And also not only a thumbnail routine, but furhter methods that have to be implemented for *every* provider, but are different from their logic. Like "create a user for providerX", or "run some cleanup routine for providerX".

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Provider {
   void specificProviderCode();
}

public class Provider1 implements Provider {
   public void specificProviderCode(){

   }
}

public class ProviderFactory{
   public static Provider createProvider(ProviderType providerType){
      if(providerType.equals(ProviderType.TYPE_1){
         return new Provider1();
      }
   }
}

@Service
public class ThumbnailService {
   public void saveForProvider(Provider provider){
       provider.specificProviderCode();
   }
}

@Service
@Async
public class ThumbnailServiceAsync {
    @Autowired
    private ThumbnailService delegator;

    public class asyncSaveForProvider(ProviderType providerType) {
        Provider url = ProviderFactory.createprovider(providerType); 
        delegator.saveForProvider(url);
    }
}
```

Now when you are adding new provider only there you need to make changes(to create new one with specific logic), both services will not be changed, which also means all callers to services do not need to change their code.

Comment: The providers each take a different parameter, so this interface does not match the question. Also this `ProviderFactory` requires modification whenever a new `ProviderType` is added, so the Open/Closed Principle is still violated, as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The [Command Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) is a great fit here.

Think of the `save` methods as instances of [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) (the basic Command interfaces in Java). If `ThumbnailService` would wrap each unique `save` method along with its unique parameter into one of these Command interfaces, then `ThumbnailServiceAsync` could become a simple [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) with no knowledge of `Providers`. The `switch` statement goes away, because the Executor treats every Command the same: by invoking `run()` or `call()`.

This leaves the question of closing `ThumbnailService` to modification. We'd like to eliminate knowledge of concrete `Providers` from that class as well. The obvious OOP approach would be to break the different logic up into separate classes, potentially into the `Providers` themselves. If you must wrap a common interface around the Providers, you may need to resort to serializing the different parameters e.g. as Strings, casting, or perhaps using reflection.

Comment: Could you give an example on how the `command pattern` could be used with my code?